# Do water hammer arresters need their packing nuts adjusted?

Tags: plumbing, water

To begin with, I'm not even sure that what I'm looking at is a packing nut, but it looks like it would operate similarly to one in shower/bathtub valves. I'm adding a [ProFlo water hammer arrester](https://www.ferguson.com/product/proflo-38-in-plastic-od-compression-x-od-female-compression-water-hammer-arrestor-pfxwhactca/_/R-7207341) (arrestor?) to my dishwasher's supply line and it looks like there's a bolt inside that can be turned with an Allen wrench. I can't find any documentation on the part that mentions this adjustment.

I'm worried that if this is a bolt that puts pressure on a packing nut, then installing the arrester without tightening it could let water get into the piston mechanism and render it ineffective. But if I tighten it too much, it could keep the piston from moving quickly enough, which would also render it ineffective.

Is this meant to be adjusted?

[image: Angle view of interior bolt/nut]

[image: Full side view of arrester]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not affect your water seal, which is the o-ring.

It's probably just an assembly detail, particularly if the instructions don't mention it.

I don't see any way it would affect the piston, which is at right angles to it.

My best *guess* (and it is a guess) is that it's a way to install an orifice (small hole of precisely known size) at the time of assembly. **EDIT:** Actually, it may just be a mechanical requirement of getting the compression nut in place, looking at it again.

Answer (score 0):

To me that’s looks like the compression type the fitting in the center is to prevent the tubing from collapsing. I have used them a few times and believe you have the same, 
they also make them with 1/2” npt fittings but I use pipe stubs when I have pipe.